# Gnustep - video recording application

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, gnustep

I don't own a mac, is it possible to create a fully functional video recording app in gnustep on windows then carry out the necessary process to deploy it as an iPad app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, no. You will, of course, be close-ish to a functioning Cocoa app if you code in GNUstep, but there are fundamental differences between the two APIs, and there are enough of them that finishing the iPad version would be a *serious* amount of work. You would need to get a Mac when it came time to finish your app, and there would be *many* hours of work invested in fixing up your GNUstep code to work with Cocoa.

Furthermore, there are specific video-related APIs available on the iPad that are simply *not* available for GNUstep. You will wind up rewriting large sections of code.

Sorry! Your best bet here is to acquire a Mac for development.

Comment: Yes, the hard part of such an application is not the language, but what you need to get right in AV Foundation for the recording and Cocoa touch for the interface.